# Determine if determinant function is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Determine whether the following are linear transformations. Explain your answers by giving an appropriate proof or counterexample.

(a) $T : M_{2,2}$ -> $\mathbb R$ defined by $T (\begin{bmatrix}a&b \\ c&d\end{bmatrix})$ = ad - bc

My solution:

It is not a linear transformation. Counterexample:

Let u = $\begin{bmatrix} 5&6 \\ 10&7 \end{bmatrix}$ and v = $\begin{bmatrix} 2&5 \\ 13&12 \end{bmatrix}$

Then:

$T(u) + T(v) = -25 -41 = -66$

$T(u+v) = -120$

The function does not preserve vector addition, and is thus not a linear transformation

Is the above solution correct? And does it do enough to prove what is required?

Comment: Your argument is correct. You can also take $u=v=$ identity matrix to make things simpler.

Comment: thank you for checking and the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p \iff q$ is the same as $\lnot p \iff \lnot q$.

You have that, $T$ is a linear transformation $\iff$ $T(u+v)= T(u)+T(v)$ and $T(\lambda u)=\lambda T(u)$

So, $T$ is a **not** a linear transformation $\iff$ $T(u+v) \ne  T(u)+T(v)$ **or** $T(\lambda u) \ne \lambda T(u)$.

So to prove that $T$ is not a linear transformation it is enough to prove one of those two.

Answer (score 1):

In general  the statements $$\det (A+B)= \det A +\det B $$ and $$\det \lambda A = \lambda \det A$$ are not true.

Thus determinant is not  a linear transformation.